# Installing secure CodeIgniter with Sparks

Tags: codeigniter, security, sparks-pakage-management

Installing Sparks assumes that you are abiding by the default CodeIgniter installation pattern; extracting the application, system, and user guide folders, along with with a index.php and a license file into your web root.

However, many of us pull the application and system folders out of the web root for security reasons and re-route the $system_path and $application_folder variables in the main index.php file.

This separation tends to break Spark installs. In particular, the simple example-spark used in the [getsparks installation instructions](http://getsparks.org/install).

Getting an error:

> An Error Was Encountered Cannot find
>   spark path at
>   sparks/example-spark/1.0.0/

I maintain the following directory structure:

- CISYS

  - V202
  - V200
- project1_application
- project2_application
- project3_application
- www (public html)

  - project1

    - css
    - js
    - images
    - etc
  - project2

    - etc

What must I reroute to achieve both security + sparks? Open to suggestions of any sort. How do you set up your installation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer my own question: The solution was in the MY_Loader.php file. By modifying the SPARKPATH variable on line 43, one can reroute the location of all sparks! Cheers!

Comment: I don't know if sparks have been updated since then, but it now checks to see if you have defined SPARKPATH. If so, it uses that, else default. I just added
`define('SPARKPATH', '../../CodeIgniter_2.1.0/sparks/');`
to my config/constants.php